# Why gradle jettyRunWar task doesn't work with java8?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, gradle, jetty, war

Using: Gradle 2.0, Spring MVC 4.0.6, Java 8

I have next `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'jetty'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    providedCompile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.0.6.RELEASE'
    runtime 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.1.2'
}

jettyRun.contextPath = ''

jettyRunWar.contextPath = ''
```

When I'm run `jettyRun` application works fine.
But when I'm run `jettyRunWar`, I got next error:

```
org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet
```

What is difference between tasks and why the second doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you use `asm` 5.0.1 or higher with Java 8.

Double check your transitive dependencies and ensure that you override the `asm` library usage to be of the newer version.

This might be what you need ...

```
dependencies {
    providedCompile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.0.6.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.ow2.asm:asm:5.0.3'
    runtime 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.1.2'
}
```

Comment: Thank you! After `clean` task it helped me. But I still don't understand why `jettyRunWar` didn't work while `jettyRun` worked.

Comment: The error was from spring's use of 'asm' library.  That specific combination needs to be updated for Java 8, as the old 'asm' libraries cannot parse Java 8 bytecode properly.  Its not a Jetty thing at all.